# How to cut binary number when moving left?

Tags: java, bit

How to cut binary number when moving left instead of expand the number of bits?

```
int num = 0b101010;
num = num << 1 // I want num to be now 01010 
num = num << 1 // I want num to be now 1010
num = num << 1 // I want num to be now 010
num = num << 1 // I want num to be now 10
```

Is there easy way to do it?

Comment: If you want the number to at some stage be `01010`, it seems like you are dealing with `String`s, not binary numbers. Just cut the leftmost character out of your `String` each iteration.

Comment: Use the AND operator to extract certain bytes. Will be a lot easier. For the first one, `num & 31`, for the second `num & 15`. You can then just shift the second operator on the & over to the right 1 every operation.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this is easy to do: make a mask with all ones (`0b111111` in your case), and use it to mask your original number using `&`. As you shift the mask right, you get the effect below:

```
Number Mask   Result
------ ------ ------
101010 011111 001010
101010 001111 001010
101010 000111 000010
101010 000011 000010
101010 000011 000010
101010 000001 000000
```

Comment: I think maybe he wants the leftmost digits to be present, shifted to the right. For example, 11110000 will be 1111000.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
int num = 0b101010;
num = num >> 4;
```

Now it is `0b10`.